# Extracting data from salesforce trigger object

Tags: trigger, soql, query

Objective here – to extract the account__r.id from the record in the trigger and add the value to a list with each for-loop…

CODE SAMPLE ONE

```
if (trigger.isinsert) {
for (loan__c oloan : trigger.new){
system.debug(oloan);
    Loan__c loanintrigger = new loan__c();
    loanintrigger = [ SELECT loan__c.name,account__r.id from loan__c WHERE loan__c.id =      : oloan.id];
    Account a = new account ();
    a.id = loanintrigger.account__r.id;
    //   debug to test insertion of value directly from trigger object.....        
    system.debug(a.id);
```

CODE SAMPLE TWO

```
if (trigger.isinsert) {
for (loan__c oloan : trigger.new){
system.debug(oloan);
    Account a = new account ();
    a.id = oloan.account__r.id;
//   debug to test insertion of value directly from trigger object.....        
    system.debug(a.id);
```

So… trigger one runs and completes its assignment. Trigger two fails due to “missing argument.”  I.e. – system.debug(a.id) shows that the id in the account object is null.

Sample one, of course, ALSO requires a query for every record in the trigger.  No style points.

This foreshadows important and vexing question (at least for me) ….   Actually, a couple of them…

Firstly, if I use the syntax /  method “a.id = oloan.name” I am able to extract and place the field value in a new list.  This is true of any field in the trigger object except lookups.  I also know from system.debug(oloan) that the all of the data fields in question are “there.”  In some critical (and not-so-obvious) way, the related account id is NOT there in (nor can it be mapped from) the trigger object.  But the name is available…..

In the context of an after delete trigger, not even #1 works because you cannot query DB for data that has been deleted!

Can anybody suggest alternate approach?  What am I missing here?

Comment: triggers don't have context into lookup or child relationships without doing a separate query. Note also that account__r.id is exactly the same as `account__c` and the latter is available to the trigger without having to query. However, account__r.name does require a query.